# How to talk to a different echo device from within an alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, home-automation

The alexa skill gets launched from echo device **Kitchen** and shall do a dialogue using echo device **Bedroom** as example.

- Is it possible at all?
- How to do it in node.js or python?

This should be done by a skill not by a routine because the actual target device is retrieved via a REST api.

This seems like a common task. Surprisingly I was not able to even figure out, if it is possible at all. Maybe it is too common.

Comment: Can you describe the CX you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to achieve the CX you described with Alexa Skill Kits today.

As an end-user, you can use the [announcement feature](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/acm/announcements-acm.html) to broadcast a message to all of your supported Alexa devices, e.g. *"Alexa, announce dinner is ready"*. You can exclude certain devices by turning on "Do Not Disturb" mode, or disabling the announcement feature in their device setting.

If you're an enterprise customer (e.g. business, healthcare, hospitality...etc.), you can use the [Alexa Smart Properties API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-smart-properties/asp-core-notifications-api.html) to send an announcement to a specific device you manage.

For ASK, the closest thing is the [Notification API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html). But [the CX is a bit different](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-proactive-events#frequently-asked-questions), like the user needs to say *"Alexa, read my notifications"*, and you can't target a specific echo device.

I'm curious about your use case. As a skill developer, why do you want to send a dialogue to a different echo device?

Comment: Thanks for your answer

The flow would be this:

1. The smarthome (i.e. home assistant) triggers skill of main echo by any channel.

2. The skill pulls REST API of smarthome for informations and gets the actual target device id.

3. A question/answer dialog is delegated to the target device.

According to your answer this would only be possible for "business, healthcare, hospitality".  Why do they sell communication devices that just can't communicate? Like cars that can't drive. Unbelievable!

I will have to take for a different approach, triggering each device separately.